# Close popup if clicking outside it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code showing a button who displays a popup, i want the user to be able to close the popup by clicking outside of it when it's open.

So i want to asign the methode "Close()" to the event listner who detect outside click of the class '.popup', for now it's only an alert.

The problem is that when i click on the button, it's start already with the alert even if the popup didn't open yet, i want the event listner to start working once the popup in open, not before.

Any suggestion to take off repetitive code is also appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
    /* Clean up the URL from '#popup1' in the end */
    history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
    

    /* Take off the popup from DOM before clicking in case user refresh*/
    let id_popup = document.querySelector('#popup1');
    let popup = id_popup.parentNode
    popup.removeChild(id_popup);

    

    /*Opening the popup*/
    function Open() {
      popup.appendChild(id_popup);
      
      let class_popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
      window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

        if (!class_popup.contains(e.target)) {
          alert('You\'re clicking outside the popup !') 
        }
      });
    }


    /*Closing the popup*/
    function Close() {
      popup.removeChild(id_popup);
      history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
    }
```

```css
  .button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000;
    border: 2px solid #06D85F;
    border-radius: 20px/50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  .button:hover {
    background: #06D85F;
  }

  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .popup {
    margin: 70px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .popup h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .popup .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: all 200ms;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
  }

  .popup .close:hover {
    color: #06D85F;
  }

  .popup .content {
    max-height: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .box {
      width: 70%;
    }

    .popup {
      width: 70%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#popup1" onclick="Open()">Let me Pop up</a>

</div>
<title>hi</title>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <a class="close" onclick="Close()" href="javascript://">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      Text

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check if you're clicking in another element besides the popup also be sure to stop the event propogation

Comment: @ImmortalDude it has to do with the methode Open() in the first place, because it's not even in the DOM before you click, event propagation is in the 'close()', right ?

Comment: Use event listeners and bind them on document ready, avoid onclick as much as possible, also I mean use `event.stopPropogation` to stop clicks from bubbling up the Dom tree

Comment: @ImmortalDude Thank you very much, it does work now, i added event.stopPropagation(); on open() method, now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let allElems = document.querySelectorAll("body > div:not(#popup1)"); // Special query selector to get everything except .popup and its children

Array.from(allElems).forEach(elem => // Convert to iterable (with Array.from) and loop through all elements selected
  elem.addEventListener('click', function (e) { // Give them all the click event listener.
    alert('You\'re clicking outside the popup !') 
  });
}
```

The issue was mostly with your `if` statement, since the `.contains` was kind of messing things up. The alternative would be to convert both the elements to strings and compare them that way, but this method is better and also faster (slightly), since we don't need to check on every single click whether it's in the box or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now it does show the alert even if you click inside the popup using this code.

Comment: @aliouawalid try now.

Comment: @aliouawalid Are you using it with `event.stopPropogation()`, like you said in the comments? See if it works then. Using the query selector is still more stable than just your current code.

Comment: No i didn't, i'll try out your code also, thank you.